# POST Method and Using an Array to Store Input

Tags: json, node.js, express

I have this bit of code here, I ask for a first name and last name, when I click the button it displays the input. My question is, if I wanted to store the input so that each time a new first_name and last_name is entered, it would display all previous entries too. How would I do that in JSON? Here is the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/index.htm', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.htm" );
})

app.post('/process_post', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {


response = {
   first_name:req.body.first_name,
   last_name:req.body.last_name
};
console.log(response);
res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {

var host = server.address().address
var port = server.address().port

 console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```